# In a Rails 3 many to many association, what is the most efficient way to query objects based on conditions on their associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a many-to-many model relation:

```
class Movie
has_many :movie_genres
has_many :genres, :through => :movie_genres

class Genre
has_many :movie_genres
has_many :movies, :through => :movie_genres

class MovieGenre
belongs_to :movie
belongs_to :genre
```

I want to query all movies with a certain genre but not associated with another genre. Example: **All movies that are Action but not Drama**.

What I have done is this:

```
action_movies = Genre.find_by_name('action').movies
drama_movies  = Genre.find_by_name('drama').movies
action_not_drama_movies = action_movies - drama_movies
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? It should be noted that the query can become more complex like: **All movies that are Action but not Drama or All movies that are Romance and Comedy**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed improve efficiency by avoid having to instantiate the `Movie` instances for all action and drama movies by removing the drama movies from the set of action movies in via the sql statement.

The basic building block is a dynamic scope similar to what [widjajayd proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46292914/3206935)

```
class Movie
  ...
  # allows to be called with a string for single genres or an array for multiple genres
  # e.g. "action" will result in SQL like `WHERE genres.name = 'action'`
  #      ["romance", "comedy"] will result in SQL like `WHERE genres.name IN ('romance', 'comedy')`
  def self.of_genre(genres_names)
    joins(:genres).where(genres: { name: genres_names })
  end
  ...
end
```

You can use that scope as a building block to get the movies you want

**All movies that are action but not drama**:

```
Movie
  .of_genre('action')
  .where("movies.id NOT IN (#{Movie.of_genre('drama').to_sql}")
```

This will result in an sql subquery. Using a join would be nicer but it should be good enough for most cases and is a better read that the join alternative.

If your app where a rails 5 application you could even type

```
Movie
  .of_genre('action')
  .where.not(id: Movie.of_genre('drama'))
```

**All movies that are Action but not Drama or All movies that are Romance and Comedy**

Because it is a rails 3 app you will have to type move most of the sql by hand and can not make a lot of use of the scope. The `or` method is only introduced in rails 5. So this will mean having to type:

```
Movie
  .joins(:genres)
  .where("(genres.name = 'action' AND movies.id NOT IN (#{Movie.of_genre('drama').to_sql}) OR genres.name IN ('romance', 'comedy')" )
```

Again, if it where a rails 5 application this would be much simpler

```
Movie
  .of_genre('action')
  .where.not(id: Movie.of_genre('drama'))
  .or(Movie.of_genre(['romance', 'comedy']))
```

Comment: Hi, this one was closest to what I finally used. It did what I want in one query. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

probably using scope is better, here is sample and explanation (but not tested), create scope in movie model as follow

Movie.rb

```
scope :action_movies, joins(movie_genre: :genre).select('movies.*','genres.*').where('genres.name  = ?', 'action')
scope :drama_movies, joins(movie_genre: :genre).select('movies.*','genres.*').where('genres.name  = ?', 'drama')
```

in your controller, you can call as follow

```
@action_movies = Movie.action_movies
@drama_movies  = Movie.drama_movies
@action_not_drama_movies = @action_movies - @drama_movies
```

#### edit for dynamic scope

if you want dynamic then you can send parameter to scope below is scope using block.

```
scope :get_movies, lambda { |genre_request|
 joins(movie_genre: :genre).select('movies.*','genres.*').where('genres.name  = ?', genre_request)
}
```

genre_request = parameter variable for scope

in your controller

```
  @action_movies = Movie.get_movies('action')
  @drama_movies  = Movie.get_movies('drama')
```

Comment: The queries that I will be using will be dynamic. I just stated action and drama as examples. So using scopes this way might not be the way to go for me. I will note this one though, thanks!

Comment: I just add additional scope for your case

Comment: I think what you added is very useful. But I'm still looking for an improvement in the query. Upvoted your answer though :)

Answer (score -1):

Don't see a way to do it with one query (not without using subqueries anyway). But here is one that I think makes it a little better:

```
scope :by_genres, lambda { |genres|
  genres = [genres] unless genres.is_a? Array
  joins(:genres).where(genres: { name: genre }).uniq
}

scope :except_ids, lambda { |ids|
  where("movies.id NOT IN (?)", ids)
}

scope :intersect_ids, lambda { |ids|
  where("movies.id IN (?)", ids)
}

## all movies that are action but not drama
action_ids = Movie.by_genres("action").ids
drama_movies = Movie.by_genres("drama").except_ids(action_ids)

## all movies that are both action and dramas
action_ids = Movie.by_genres("action").ids
drama_movies = Movie.by_genres("drama").intersect_ids(action_ids)

## all movies that are either action or drama
action_or_drama_movies = Movie.by_genres(["action", "drama"])
```

It's possible to do except and intersect with raw SQL in Rails. But I think that's in general not a good idea as it still requires more than one query and also might make the code dependent on the DB used.

---

My original answer is rather naive. I'll leave it here so others won't make the same mistake:

Use `joins` and you can get it with one query:

```
Movie.joins(:genres).where("genres.name = ?", "action").where("genres.name != ?", "drama")
```

As noted in the comments, this will get all the movies that are both action and drama too.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer. The issue I encountered using this is that in my result, I still get those movies with **drama** genre if they also have the **action** genre.

Comment: oh indeed. Sorry can't think of a way to do it in one query.